# Merge every n items in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to solve the following Ruby puzzle on CodeWars:

> Write a function called `merge_every` that accepts 3 arguments: 2 arrays
>   and a number which indicates the amount of items to insert the second
>   arrays items into the first. The third argument is optional and should
>   default to `4`.
>
> Think of it as you have an array of normal events and array of
>   featured events, and you want to merge the two to result in an array
>   of events with a featured one showing up every, say, 3 items.
>
> ```
> event_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
> featured_event_ids = [10, 11]
> merge_every(event_ids, featured_event_ids, 3)
> # => [1, 2, 3, 10, 4, 5, 6, 11, 7]
> ```
>
> If the first array should complete before the second, the rest of the
>   second is dropped. Whereas, if the second runs out before the first,
>   the entirety of the first array should be preserved. Should count be 0
>   or less, no items should be inserted and if the target array is empty,
>   than an empty array should be returned.
>
> More Examples
>
> ```
> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
> merge_every(numbers, letters)
> # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 'a', 5, 6, 7, 8, 'b', 9, 10]
>
> merge_every(letters, numbers)
> # => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>
> merge_every(letters, numbers, 2)
> # => ['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd']
> ```

My Solution is:

```
def merge_every(target, source, count=4)

  count == 0 ? number_of_source_in_target = 0 : number_of_source_in_target = target.count / count
  insertion_number = count
  source_number = 0

    if insertion_number == 0 || source.count == 0 || number_of_source_in_target <= 1
        target
    elsif target.count % insertion_number == 0
      number_of_source_in_target -= 1
      while source_number < number_of_source_in_target && source_number < source.count do
        modulo_0_return = target.insert(insertion_number, source[source_number])
        insertion_number += (count + 1)
        source_number += 1
      end
      modulo_0_return
    else
      while source_number < number_of_source_in_target && source_number < source.count do
          modulo_numbers_return = target.insert(insertion_number, source[source_number])
          insertion_number += (count + 1)
          source_number += 1
      end
      modulo_numbers_return
    end
end

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print merge_every(numbers, letters, 3)
```

When I run my code on my computer I get the correct answer, but on the CodeWars website, their checker gives a different output. The differences occur with:

```
merge_every(numbers, letters, 3)
# My Terminal: [1, 2, 3, 'a', 4, 5, 6, 'b', 7, 8, 9, 'c', 10]
# CodeWars "checker": [1, 2, 3, "a", 4, "a", 5, "b", 6, 7, 8, "c", "b", 9, 10]

merge_every(numbers, letters, 1)
# My Terminal: [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# CodeWars "checker": [1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "c", "a", "d", 4, "a", 5, "b", 6, 7, 8, "c", "b", 9, 10]
```

I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me figure out this discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what code wars is doing but it may be that it's running your method more than once.  One of the things that your code does is mutate the array `target` so if you do..

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
merge_every(numbers, letters, 3)
=> [1, 2, 3, 'a', 4, 5, 6, 'b', 7, 8, 9, 'c', 10]
```

But then if you check `numbers` you'll see they're changed...

```
p numbers
=> [1, 2, 3, 'a', 4, 5, 6, 'b', 7, 8, 9, 'c', 10]
```

So your numbers array is changed, and every time you run `merge_every` with the same input object you get a different result (and mutate the `numbers` array again)

You could try ensuring you run your code on a duplicate (copy) of the array instead of the array itself... an array that looks the same but is a different object. That way when the code mutates `target` the original input arry is unchanged.

```
def merge_every(target, source, count=4)
  target = target.dup
  ...
```

Comment: Using target.dup helped in the "checker". It ran correctly and gave the same output as in Terminal. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is an option using built in features [`Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), maybe you can test also in codewar to see if there is some issue:

```
n = 3
event_ids.each_slice(n).zip(featured_event_ids).flatten.compact
#=> [1, 2, 3, "a", 4, 5, 6, "b", 7]
```

Checking how it works maybe can provide an hint.
It is required to add a condition to avoid this result, for example with `n=6`:

```
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "a", 7, "b"]
```

Comment: This helped a lot with refining my code. Thank you. There were a few methods here unknown to me, but I have researched them and combined them with my previous code to produce my final answer.

`code`
def merge_every(target, source, count=4)
 if target.count == 0 || source.count == 0 || count <= 0  
  target  
 else  
  total_in_final_array = target.count + target.count / count  
  target.count % count == 0 ? total_in_final_array -= 1 : total_in_final_array  
  target.each_slice(count).zip(source).flatten.compact.take(total_in_final_array)  
  end  
end

Answer (score 0):

If your code passes your tests, but not CodeWar's, the most likely explanation is that your tests are incorrect or, more likely, incomplete.

Here is one Ruby-like way to perform the insertions.

```
def insert_em(arr, insertions, after_every = 4)
  return arr if after_every <= 0
  enum_arr = arr.to_enum
  isize = insertions.size
  arr.size.times.with_object([]) do |i,a|
    a << enum_arr.next
    a << insertions[i/after_every] if
      i <= after_every*isize && ((i+1) % after_every).zero?
  end
end

arr = (1..10).to_a

insert_em(arr, [:a, :b, :c],  -1)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
insert_em(arr, [:a, :b, :c],  0)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
insert_em(arr, [:a, :b, :c],  1)
  #=> [1, :a, 2, :b, 3, :c, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
insert_em(arr, [:a, :b, :c],  2)
  #=> [1, 2, :a, 3, 4, :b, 5, 6, :c, 7, 8, 9, 10]
insert_em(arr, [:a, :b, :c],  4)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, :a, 5, 6, 7, 8, :b, 9, 10]
insert_em(arr, [:a, :b, :c],  5)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, :a, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, :b]
insert_em(arr, [:a, :b, :c], 11)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
insert_em(arr, [])
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
insert_em([], [:a, :b, :c])
  #=> []
insert_em([], [])
  #=> []
```